# Milliseconds compare in php

Tags: php, date, time

```
$date1 = "2017-04-13 09:09:80:300" 
$date2 = "2017-04-13 09:09:80:400"
```

how can I check if the `date2` is more or less 100 milliseconds then `$date 1` in  and false if not (101 - more or less)

Answer (score 5):

Your question, while deceptively appearing simple, is actually fairly ugly, because it is the case that PHP's [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function truncates milliseconds from a timestamp.  Actually, it won't even correctly process the timestamps `$date1` and `$date2` which you have in your question.  One workaround is to trim off the millisecond portion of the timestamp, use `strtotime()` to get milliseconds since the epoch, then use a regex to obtain and add the millisecond portion to this amount.

```
$date1 = "2017-04-13 09:09:40:300";
$date2 = "2017-04-13 09:09:40:400";

preg_match('/^.+:(\d+)$/i', $date1, $matches);
$millis1 = $matches[1];
$ts1 = strtotime(substr($date1, 0, 18))*1000 + $millis1;
preg_match('/^.+:(\d+)$/i', $date2, $matches);
$millis2 = $matches[1];
$ts2 = strtotime(substr($date2, 0, 18))*1000 + $millis2;

if (abs($ts1 - $ts2) < 100) {
    echo "within 100 millseconds";
}
else {
    echo "not within 100 millseconds";
}
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: No No No it can't be that easy! +1

Comment: @HankyPanky If this were the same question in Postgres, I would already be running :-)

Comment: Have you tried it? It makes no sense. Miliseconds are stripped on to seconds comparison... It will return true if difference in ms is 999

Comment: @HankyPanky it is not

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's still wrong after your edit. `1990-04-13 09:09:80:300` and `2017-04-13 09:09:80:300` will return true

Comment: @Peter What an awful language PHP is, their date API is almost as bad as Java (well, Java 7 and earlier, Java 8 is not so bad).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yep you'll have to reinvent the wheel in PHP if you want to write let's say lap timer application

Answer (score 5):

If you get your time in such format (I changed `09:09:80` to `09:09:40` as it was incorrect format)

```
$date1 = "2017-04-13 09:09:40:300" 
$date2 = "2017-04-13 09:09:40:400"
```

create custom function since `strtotime` doesn't support ms

```
function myDateToMs($str) {
   list($ms, $date) = array_map('strrev', explode(":", strrev($str), 2));
   $ts = strtotime($date);
   if ($ts === false) {
       throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Wrong date format");
   }
   return $ts * 1000 + $ms;
}
```

now just check does difference is less than 100

```
$lessOrEqual100 = abs(myDateToMs($date1) - myDateToMs($date2)) <= 100;
```

Comment: Your answer is cleaner than mine +1.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [php manual for strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php) fractions of a second are allowed, although currently ignored by the `strtotime` function.

This means you could express your dates like this `2017-04-13 09:00:20.100` to have them parsed by strtotime without error (keeping them futureproofed) and then use a custom function to compare just the millisecond portion of the dates *if the timestamps are the same*

The below function will return true if the dates are within 100 milliseconds, false otherwise. You can pass in the amount to compare them by as an argument.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set ( "UTC" );

$date1 = "2017-04-13 09:00:20.100";
$date2 = "2017-04-13 09:00:20.300";

// pass date1, date2 and the amount to compare them by
$res = compareMilliseconds($date1,$date2,100);
var_dump($res);

function compareMilliseconds($date1,$date2,$compare_amount){

  if(strtotime($date1) == strtotime($date2)){

      list($throw,$milliseond1) = explode('.',$date1);
      list($throw,$milliseond2) = explode('.',$date2);

      return ( ($milliseond2 - $milliseond1) < $compare_amount);
  }

}


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP 7.1 lets you do it with DateTime objects...

Be sure to test all other answers with a change of day as a true indicator of a successful process.

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c2d9300c5968230cc074b2ce162af06a8fe814c7)

Code:

```
$dt1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s:u e', "2017-04-14 0:00:00:000 UTC");
$dt2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s:u e', "2017-04-13 23:59:59:999 UTC");
var_export($dt1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s:u'));
echo "\n";
var_export($dt2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s:u'));
echo "\n";
//var_export($dt1->diff($dt2));
echo "\n";
$diff=$dt1->diff($dt2);
// cast $diff as an array so array_intersect_assoc() can be used
if(sizeof(array_intersect_assoc(['y'=>0,'m'=>0,'d'=>0,'h'=>0,'i'=>0],(array)$diff))==5){
    // years, months, days, hours, and minutes are all 0
    var_export($micro=round(abs($diff->s+$diff->f),3));
    // combine seconds with microseconds then test
    echo "\n";
    if($micro>.1){
        echo "larger than .1";
    }else{
        echo "less than or equal to .1";
    }
}else{
    echo "too large by units larger than seconds";
}
```

Outputs:

```
'2017-04-14 00:00:00:000000'
'2017-04-13 23:59:59:999000'

0.001
less than or equal to .1
```